# Using jQuery to sum several input fields based on a partial match in name attribute

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table of several rows, each with 12 columns (one per month). At the end of each row is a "Total" field.

The input fields each have a systematic name, say:

```
name="variable1_jan", name="variable1_feb"
```

etc.

I would like to reference these fields by the partial match (i.e. all the fields which have a name including "variable1_", and sum across all of them, putting the resulting sum in the total field, on keyup (across input fields).

**Truncated example of a table row:**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="" title="jan" id="" name="r_inpatient_jan" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="" title="feb" id="" name="r_inpatient_feb" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="" title="tot" id="" name="r_inpatient_tot" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

My goal: jQuery that will find all input fields where name contains (in this example) "r_inpatient" and sum them, then place that value in "r_inpatient_tot". Is this possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this should work:

```
$("input[name^=r_inpatient]").keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[name^=r_inpatient]").not("input[name=r_inpatient_tot]").each(function() {
        var number = parseInt(this.value) || 0;
        sum += number
    });
    $("input[name=r_inpatient_tot]").val(sum);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x2BE3/

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vS8R/)

```
$("input[name^=r_inpatient]").keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[name^=r_inpatient]").not("input[name=r_inpatient_tot]").each(function () {
        sum += (parseInt(this.value) ? parseInt(this.value) : 0);
    });
    $("input[name=r_inpatient_tot]").val(sum);
});
```

References

[attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

[.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)